# How can I read the Ids' on of div element for li tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the Ids of all the li elements under div text.

```
<div id="editSortable"> 
<ul class="sortable-list  ui-sortable">
    <li id="id1">Test 1</li>
    <li id="id2">Test 2</li>
    <li id="id3">Test 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I need output as id1, id2, id3 as a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this. It will work for you.

```
var ids = [];
$("#editSortable").find("li").each(function () { ids.push(this.id); });
var result = ids.join(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use `attr("id")` to get the id of each li
2. You need to iterate each li to get each id using `.each()`
3. You can use `.map()` to get all id into an array

```js
$('#editSortable').find('li').each(function() {
  console.log(this.id) //more efficient way to get id of an element
  //console.log($(this).attr("id"))//another way to get an id of element
})

var arr = $('#editSortable').find('li').map(function() {
  return ($(this).attr("id"))
}).get();

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editSortable">
  <ul class="sortable-list  ui-sortable">
    <li id="id1">Test 1</li>
    <li id="id2">Test 2</li>
    <li id="id3">Test 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `this.id` gives you the same result as `$(this).attr('id')`.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes giving the jquery one

Comment: Yeah, but `this.id` works within the jQuery function, and is easier to read and rather more efficient.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes youre right because jquery is just js im just more familiar with js than jquery which is wrong/not good practice :( i will add the this.id

Answer (score 0):

while *You need output as id1, id2, id3 as a string* .. [way of ways] you can use `.each()` and save ids by `+=` adding them to a variable join by comma except the last one

**Demo**

```js
var Ids= '';
$('#editSortable .sortable-list li').each(function(){
     var comma = $(this).index() + 1 == $('#editSortable .sortable-list li').length ? '' : ',';
     Ids += this.id + comma;
});

console.log(Ids)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editSortable"> 
    <ul class="sortable-list  ui-sortable">
        <li id="TEXT_1">Test 1</li>
        <li id="TEXT_2">Test 2</li>
        <li id="TEXT_3">Test 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easily done by this way.

```js
$("#editSortable ul li").each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr("id"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editSortable"> 
<ul class="sortable-list  ui-sortable">
    <li id="id1">Test 1</li>
    <li id="id2">Test 2</li>
    <li id="id3">Test 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```